# Error with form data, trying to validate with PHP

Tags: php, forms, joomla, validation

So I have this form on a page and trying to validate values with PHP, then send the e-mail off. I'm using the Joomla CMS as well. The form submits but none of the values transmit over. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas to what is going on? Thanks in advance.

http://www.indigoeastend.com/same-sex-weddings

```
    <?php echo ''; //error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED); ?>
    <?php flush(); ?>
    <table style="margin-top:1.2em;">
    <tr>
    <td class="wedding_left">
    <p style="margin-top:0;">New York has said "I do" to same-sex marriage and for your New York wedding choose Hotel Indigo. Here you'll experience all the beauty that can be found on Long Island's famous East End. Right next door to vineyards, beaches the North Fork and the Hamptons we can provide a multitude of wedding event options. Our newly designed hotel offers a chic, contemporary and cosmopolitan setting that will set the stage for your ideal affair.  Hotel Indigo provides a boutique private experience hosting only one wedding at a time–yours.</p>

    <p>Our wedding planner will work with you to create a completely custom event in our exquisitely appointed ballroom or create a tented outdoor space by fascinating poolscape and cabanas. Hotel Indigo features stunning landscapes for photography and stylish areas for your guests to gather and enjoy themselves.</p>

    <p>Our catering team can provide you with a custom menu serving your favorite dishes and signature drinks. We can arrange your beach excursions, wine tours and spa treatments so you and your guests can truly appreciate the NY wedding of your dreams on the East End.</p>
    </td>
    <td class="wedding_right">

    <h1 style="word-spacing:-.15em; margin:0 0 5px 0 !important; font-size:1.5em;">TOUR FOR THE DAY &<br />
    STAY FOR THE NIGHT!</h1>
    <p style="margin-top:0;">
    <b style="color:#1f407e;">Come tour the hotel as a possible venue for your upcoming wedding and receive 
    a free overnight stay*</b>

    <p>Please provide the following information:</p>

    <?php
    $good_to_go = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    } else {
        $first_name = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    } else {
        $last_name = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
        $email = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    } else {
        $phone = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submitIt'])) {
        $submitIt = $_POST['submitIt'];
    } else {
        $submitIt = 0;
    }

    echo 'NAME: '.$first_name.' ';
    echo $last_name.'<br />';
    echo 'EMAIL: '.$email.'<br />';
    echo 'PHONE: '.$phone.'<br />';

    if($submitIt == 1) {
            echo 'WORKS!';
        if ($first_name == '' && $last_name == '' && $email == '' && $phone == '') {
            echo "<p class='red'  style='color:red;'>ERROR: Please fill the form out before submitting it.</p>";
            $good_to_go = 0;
        } elseif ($first_name == '' || $last_name == '' || $email == '' || $phone == '') {
            if($first_name == '') {
                echo "<p class='red no_margin' style='color:red;'>ERROR: Please enter your first name.</p>";
                //$good_to_go = 0;
            }

            if($last_name == '') {
                echo "<p class='red no_margin' style='color:red;'>ERROR: Please enter your last name.</p>";
                //$good_to_go = 0;
            }

            if($phone == '') {
                echo "<p class='red no_margin' style='color:red;'>ERROR: Please enter a phone number.</p>";
                //$good_to_go = 0;
            }

            if(!ereg("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) {
                echo "<p class='red no_margin' style='color:red;'>ERROR: Please enter a valid e-mail.</p>";
                //$good_to_go = 0;
                $email = '';
            }
        } else {
            if(!ereg("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) {
                echo "<p class='red' style='color:red;'>ERROR: Please enter a valid e-mail.</p>";
                //$good_to_go = 0;
            } else {
                //send that puppy!
                $mydate = date ( 'l, F d Y g:i A',time()+240 );

                $to = 'drottino@viridian-graphics.com';

                //e-mail subject
                $subject = 'Someone has submitted a form via the website';

                //e-mail message
                $message = "I am interested in the hotel tour.\r\n\r\n\r\n"

                //."Subject: $contact_subject\r\n"
                ."<b>SUBMITTED ON:</b> ".$mydate."\r\n"
                //."<b>FROM IP:</b> {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}\r\n\r\n"
                ."<b>CONTACT NAME:</b> ".$first_name." ".$last_name."\r\n"
                ."<b>MESSAGE:</b> ".$message."\r\n\n";
                //."<b>FORM ADDRESS:</b> {$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

                $headers = "From: $first_name $last_name <$email>\n"
                ."Reply-To: ".strip_tags($email)."\n"
                ."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
                ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

                $good_to_go = 1;
            }
        }
    } else {

    }
    ?>

    <?php if ($good_to_go == 0) { ?>
        <form method="post" action="http://www.indigoeastend.com/same-sex-weddings">
            <p><label for="first_name">FIRST NAME</label><br />
            <input type="text" size="30" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" /></p>

            <p><label for="last_name">LAST NAME</label></br >
            <input type="text" size="30" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" /></p>

            <p><label for="email">E-MAIL ADDRESS</label><br />
            <input type="text" size="30" name="email" value=""/></p>

            <p><label for="phone">PHONE NUMBER</label><br />
            <input type="text" size="30" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" /></p>

            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submitIt">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
        </form>
    <?php } else
            //mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); ?>
        <p>Thank you for submitting your request. We will get back to you shortly.</p>
    <?php } ?>

    <p>Subject to a one hour tour of the<br />
    hotel, advance notice required for<br />
    tour and stay offer.</p>

    <p>*Valid for any 1 night stay sunday–thursday and subject to availability.</p>
    <hr />
    </p>Speak with our wedding planners<br />
    to plan your unique affair<br />
    631.369.2200 | dmazza@eastendhotels.com<br />
    <a href="mailto:dmazza@eastendhotels.com">contact us</a></p>

    <p>Ballroom for up to 240 guests<br />
    Outdoor Tented Space<br />
    Gazebo for ceremonies<br />
    Stylishly furnished Poolscape<br />
    Restaurant & Private Dining Room for rehearsal dinners and brunches<br />
    After-parties<br />
    Transportation planning services<br />
    Hospitality areas<br />
    Bridal Suite & Guest accommodations</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You see nothing if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: My eyees they burn... Does Joomla really roll with inline html, php, css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at line 142.. here, you were  missing the { after else. It should be :

```
<?php } else {
            //mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); ?>
        <p>Thank you for submitting your request. We will get back to you shortly.</p>
    <?php } ?>
```

I did run the code, and it works fine, i can get the submitted values, eg.

```
NAME: asdf sasa
EMAIL: asdf@deded.com
PHONE: 123
WORKS!

Thank you for submitting your request. We will get back to you shortly
```

Comment: Not bad fellas, record time too. But I'm now having a problem with updating the form values. Like if you miss a field or type in an invalid e-mail. When you correct and resend the info, it won't update.

Comment: @Dave Rottino what you want to do?

Comment: Nevermind, a little bit of focus and a lot of headbanging (not the good metal kind) and I got it. Had to turn the cache off in the site configuration. Would rather have it off for this particular page rather than globally for the site but I am under time constraints to get this page live. Thanks though.

Comment: great ! if it solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer :)